# Can you assign material to 2 neighboring faces in a collection with Geo Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

So I was hoping If there was a way to assign material to the faces from separate objects in a collection; highlighted in blue.

My first attempt in setting up the geometry nodes is as follows.

1. set material to "internal Material"
2. Select only faces from the collection counted by "face neighbors

[image]

here's what the current result looks like in viewport shading.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's understandable why you'd think that, but `Face Neighbors`—*Face Count* does not refer to faces close to each other in 3D space, it simply [counts the number of other faces that connect to a face (with at least one edge)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/face_neighbors.html). For example, if you had a pyramid, it would give you the number $3$ for each side face of the pyramid (since they are all connected to two other faces on their two sides, in addition to the bottom face), and it would give $4$ for the bottom face (since it's connected to all four side faces with an edge).

The node you're looking for that would give you access to "close-by faces of another geometry" is `Geometry Proximity`. In the screeshot below, I have a sphere as my main object, and a collection with two objects (a monkey and a cone) in it. Using the *Geometry Proximity*—*Distance* output, I'm checking which of my sphere's faces are less than 2 meters close to the faces of the collection objects, then painting them black. `Object Info` and `Collection Info` nodes give you instances, so to get the positions of individual faces, I need to realize them first. Cone is closer than the monkey, so more faces get painted on that side.

Note that in your screenshot you're simply transferring the information which says how many face neighbors each face has, all of it at once; it's not *filtering* that information, so it wouldn't work as a *Selection*. The `Compare` node (set to *Less Than*) I'm using is handling that filtering job here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is pretty Dang Close to what I was looking for. And I appreciate the quick feedback!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you mark it as accepted, then? (Hit the checkmark at the top-left of the answer)

Comment: while this is a close solution, it's not the solution I was looking for. Geometry Proximity will not only change material on those 3 faces, it will also overlap the top and borttom faces too. Im looking for a solution that where the specified faces change material when they occupy the same space. that being said, if the current build (3.33.1) does not have a node solution that could support this, then I'll award you the answer.

Comment: I can replicate your setup fine, here: https://i.imgur.com/nYrol2W.png Just use "Equal=0" instead of "Less than" and it should work. Note that for the distance, it uses the weight center of faces.